# Is it possible to run code inside of an SKAction sequence that isn't an SKAction?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sequence, skaction, sktexture

I have this SKAction sequence:

```
    func move(){

    let recursive = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.moveByX(frame.size.width/2.8, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(randomNumber())),
        SKAction.moveByX(-frame.size.width/2.8, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(randomNumber())),
        SKAction.runBlock({self.move()})])
        doc.runAction(recursive, withKey: "move")
}
```

When this part below runs, I want to change the texture property of my node, but I can't figure out how to add that into the SKAction sequence.

```
SKAction.moveByX(frame.size.width/2.8, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(randomNumber()))
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you add another runBlock call?

```
SKAction.runBlock(
{ 
      //change the texture and whatever else you need here...
      doc.texture = someNewTexture;
})
```